# Reactor flux with replay not always working

Tags: java, libgdx, project-reactor

I'm currently working on a game in which the user can run spells, these spells can both require and supply input of certain POJO types, these I have depicted by `ArgType<T>`. Rather than storing these requests *and* pre-supplied objects and then constantly checking for any matches I decided to make this entire system more dynamic, using project reactor;
Spells now use this method in `ArgumentRequestor` to request 'arguments'

```java
public <T> Mono<T> get(ArgType<T> argType) {
        if (!memoryReadQueue.isEmpty()) {
            //(...)
        }
        Mono<T> mono;
        mono = Mono.create(tMonoSink -> inputRequestFluxSink.tryEmitNext(new ArgumentRequest<T>(argType, tMonoSink)));
        return mono;
    }
```

with `ArgumentRequest<T>` being a simple record with an added boolean `handled` which keeps track of whether the request has been handled.

Then to make the flux sink and its respective flux;

```java
private final Sinks.Many<ArgumentRequest> inputRequestFluxSink = Sinks.many().replay().limit(5, Duration.ofSeconds(3));

private final Flux<ArgumentRequest> requestFlux = inputRequestFluxSink.asFlux();
```

If any argument is provided, be it before or after being requested, it is submitted as follows;

```java
requestor.getRequestFlux().filter(a -> a.argType() == getSelectorType()).filter(argumentRequest1 -> !argumentRequest1.isHandled()).take(1).subscribe(a -> {
            a.setHandled();
            a.consumer().success(provided);
        });
```

Now I have two spells:

1. one 'selector' spell which submits a `Vector2` for the position of the mouse called `MousePosSelector`
2. one spell which requests a `Vector2` instance called `TeleportSpell`

The wanted behavior is as follows;

- If the teleport spell is called before the selector, a new instance of `ArgumentRequest` is created and put into the flux, it will wait there in the `repeat()` queue for either three seconds or until it has been followed up by 5 new requests, the selector will then subscibe, and if on time will, through `take(1)`, find this request and fulfill it, thus sending the Mono out to the teleport spell.
- If the teleport spell is called after the selector, the selector will already have subscribed and will receive the ArgumentRequest directly.

Currently only the last scenario works, however, to double-check I've run the following unit test. This emulates the first scenario with a 700 ms delay between calls.

```java
    @Test
    void checkArguments() throws InterruptedException {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int x = random.nextInt();
            int y = random.nextInt();
            Mono<Vector2> mono = quantaMain.argumentRequestor.get(ArgumentRequestor.ArgType.VECTOR2);
            AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
            mono.subscribe(vector2 -> {
                System.out.println("Vector found: X=" + vector2.getX() + "; Y=" + vector2.getY());
                Assertions.assertEquals(vector2.getX(), x);
                Assertions.assertEquals(vector2.getY(), y);
                flag.set(true);
            });
            Thread.sleep(700);
            quantaMain.argumentRequestor.getRequestFlux().filter(a -> a.argType() == ArgumentRequestor.ArgType.VECTOR2).filter(argumentRequest1 -> !argumentRequest1.isHandled()).take(1).subscribe(argumentRequest -> {
                        argumentRequest.setHandled();
                        argumentRequest.consumer().success(new Vector2(x, y));
                    });
            Assertions.assertTrue(flag.get());
        }
    }
```

In this test case it works perfectly fine for any delay below 3000ms, this has only confused me further.
Some observations:

- This test is runned without initializing libGDX/LWJGL
- The first situation does work when I wait for about a second or two
- The first situation works the second time the selector spell is ran
- If the first situation is executed a second time directly after a 'succesfull' case with the selector being ran twice, the first situation only works after running the selector thrice.
- If the first situation is then done again it requires the selector to be ran four times.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong / could be going wrong with this code? Just some tips for debugging would be greatly appreciated, since I've been stuck on this for a week now :(